# Tikz: Placing a node relative to the (rectangular) coordinates of another

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, coordinates

How do I place one `node` relative to the coordinates of another? In theory:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (source) {X};
    \node (destn) {Y} at source.coordinates +(2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

would produce something like:

```
       Y
X
```

I am aware of `right=of somenode` and similar keys, but they appear to use polar coordinates: a node that is `below right=of somenode` will not be vertically aligned with something else positioned `right=of somenode`.

How can this be done?

---

Check this out: I am doing something not much more complicated than the examples you guys posted. Even though I have `positioning` loaded, *the three adders aren't vertically aligned*. (This is what had led me to believe this syntax used polar coordinates)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Place everything
    \node (source) {\(X\)};
    \coordinate[right= of source] (split) {};

    \node [circle, draw, above right=of split] (adder1) {\(+\)} ;
    \node [circle, draw, right=of split] (adder2) {\(+\)};
    \node [circle, draw, below right=of split] (adder3) {\(+\)};

    % Place edges
    \draw [->] (source) -- (split);
    \draw [->] (split) |- (adder1);
    \draw [->] (split) -- (adder2);
    \draw [->] (split) |- (adder3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The syntax with `shift` works, so that is what I am using for the time being, although it would be nice to use the more semantic one.

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

If you load `positioning` library, then `below right=of` will  be vertically aligned with a `right=of` node. However, you can use `shift` to put a node relative to an existing node.  Further, you can also hard code the distances using `positioning` library.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (source) {X};
    \node (destn)  at ([shift={(2,1)}]source) {Y};
  \end{tikzpicture}

  With \verb|positioning| library

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (source) {X};
    \node[below right= of source] (destn)   {Y};
    \node[right= of source] (destnn)   {Y};
  \end{tikzpicture}

  With \verb|positioning| library and hard coded distances

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (source) {X};
    \node[below right= 2cm and 3cm of source] (destn)   {Y};
    \node[right= 3cm of source] (destnn)   {Y};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Similar to Harish's answer with more details on positioning syntax

I think there is a confusion about the `positioning` syntax. It doesn't use polar coordinates but if given only one argument it applies to both horizontal and vertical shifts. So you can say `below right = <horizontal shift> and <vertical shift> of <ref>`

Also it changes the anchor of the to-be-placed object to the opposite of the key given. In other words, if you say `below = of a` then the object automatically assumes `anchor=north`, or similarly if you say `above right= of a` then the object automatically assumes `anchor=below left`

Here is a test example

```
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (source) {X};
    \node (test) at ([shift={(2,1)}]source) {t};
    \node[above right=1cm and 2cm of source.center,anchor=center] (destn) {Y};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The problem you have is well explained in [`pgfmanual`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf), section "17.5.3 Advanced Placement Options". It's a long section but it's worth to read it.

```
\node [circle, draw, right=of split] (adder2) {\(+\)};
```

`right=of split` is equivalent to `right=1cm of split` which shifts `adder2` 1cm right from `split` and fixes `adder2` anchor to `west`.

```
\node [circle, draw, above right=of split] (adder1) {\(+\)};
```

`above right= of split` is equivalent to `above right=1cm of split` (which is different from `above right=1cm and 1cm of split`).

From `pgfmanual`

> When the `<shifting part>` is of the form `<number or dimension>`, the node is shifted by this `<number or dimension>` in the direction of 135º. This means that there is a difference between a `<shifting part>` of `1cm` and of `1cm and 1cm`: In the second case, the node is shifted by 1cm upward and 1cm to the right; in the ﬁrst case it is shifted by
>   1/2√2cm upward and by the same amount to the right.

And once shifted, the anchor is set to `south west`. And this is where the vertical alignment problem starts. `adder1` and `adder2` are circular nodes, and in circular nodes `west` and `south west` anchors are not on the same vertical like in rectangular nodes, as it's shown in following figures:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (2,2);

    \coordinate (split) at (0,0) {};

    \node [draw=red, above right=1cm and 1cm of split] (adder1) {\(+\)} ;
    \node [draw=green, above right=1cm of split] (adder1) {\(+\)} ;
    \node [draw, right=1cm of split] (adder1) {\(+\)} ;
    \draw[dotted] (1,0) arc[start angle=0,end angle=90,radius=1cm]; 

\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (2,2);

    \coordinate (split) at (0,0) {};

    \node [circle, draw=red, above right=1cm and 1cm of split] (adder1) {\(+\)} ;
    \node [circle, draw=green, above right=1cm of split] (adder1) {\(+\)} ;
    \node [circle, draw, right=1cm of split] (adder1) {\(+\)} ;
    \draw[dotted] (1,0) arc[start angle=0,end angle=90,radius=1cm]; 
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In case you want to vertically align circular nodes declared with `above right`, the only solution I know is explicitly setting `anchor=center` after all.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (2,2);

\coordinate (split) at (0,0) {};

\node [circle, draw=red, above right=1cm and 1cm of split, anchor=center] (adder1) {\(+\)} ;
\node [circle, draw=green, above right=1cm of split, anchor=center] (adder1) {\(+\)} ;
\node [circle, draw, right=1cm of split, anchor=center] (adder1) {\(+\)} ;
\draw[dotted] (1,0) arc[start angle=0,end angle=90,radius=1cm]; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```